# Compare ValueForKey of an array with an NSString

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I have an NSString which contains the folderName and i have an array which looks like this,

```
DATA (
    {
    FolderName = Posteingang;
    ID = 13000;
},
    {
    FolderName = Freigaben;
    ID = 13001;
},
    {
    FolderName = "My Drive";
    ID = 13002;
},
    {
    FolderName = gsb;
    ID = 13164;
},
    {
    FolderName = "my folder";
    ID = 13183;
}
```

I would like to compare the array data with the NSString so i can remove the values from the string that do not match.

```
for (NSString *FileName in ParsedData)
    {

        NSRange FileNameRange = [FileName rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if (FileNameRange.location == NSNotFound) {

            [SearchData removeObject:[SearchData valueForKey:@"FolderName"]];

        }
    }
```

I have this Fast Enumeration method and i have the Array SearchData. The enumeration method looks for the data in the array and if that data is not found then it should remove it from the array.The SearchData array is to be displayed in a tableview.

I have been trying the above method but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *searchText = @"Posteingang";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"FolderName = %@",searchText];
NSMutableArray *predarr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[yourDATAArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
if([predarr count]!=0)
{
     NSLog(@"%@",predarr);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this :

```
NSString *matchString = @"Posteingang";
for (int i = 0; i > [dataArray count]; i++) // Here dataArray is your array
{
    NSMutableDictionary *allDict = [dataArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([[allDict objectForKey:@"FolderName"] isEqualToString:matchString]) {
        [dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
    }

}
```

hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *stringToBeMatched = @"Freigaben";

for (NSDictionary *itemDic in array)
{
     if ([[itemDic objectForKey:@"FolderName"] isEqualToString:stringToBeMatched])
     {
         [dataArray removeObject:itemDic];
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
NSArray *folders = @[@{@"FolderName":@"Posteingang",@"ID":@13000},
                     @{@"FolderName":@"Freigaben",@"ID":@13001},
                     @{@"FolderName":@"My Drive",@"ID":@13002},
                     @{@"FolderName":@"gsb",@"ID":@13164},
                     @{@"FolderName":@"my folder",@"ID":@13183}];

NSString *searchText = @"gsB";
//Choose a predicate that you want
//Case insensitive and diacritic search
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"FolderName LIKE [cd] %@",searchText];
//Case sensitive search
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"FolderName = %@",searchText];
//Any Matches
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"FolderName CONTAINS [cd] %@",searchText];

NSArray *filteredArray = [folders filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

EDIT : Filtering using fast enumeration

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in [SearchData copy]){

    NSString *folderName = dict[@"FolderName"];
    if([searchText localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:folderName]){

         [SearchData removeObject:dict];

    }

 }
```

Comment: @RANA Your enumeration is faulty. I assume `ParsedData` is an array of dictionary objects. `SearchData` is also an array of dictionary but only has `ID` and `FolderName`. Each enumerated object would be a dictionary not a string.

Comment: that is exactly what i want

Comment: @RANA I haved added a code using fast enumeration, see if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: NSString *folderName = dict[@"FolderName"]; this Gives an error saying "Array Subscript is not an integer"

Comment: I assumed both your `ParsedData` and `SearchData` are array with dictionary objects. It seems like they are not, can you provide how you are forming both with their logs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29346/discussion-between-anupdas-and-rana)

Answer (score 2):

After a little help from all the answers above i figured out the solution on my own

```
    for (NSDictionary *dict in [SearchData copy]){

        NSString *folderName = [dict objectForKey:@"FolderName"];

        NSRange range= [folderName rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch]; 
        if(range.location == NSNotFound){
             [SearchData removeObject:dict];

        }

    }
```

Comment: Good to know that you have found a solution. But I would suggest you not to use this, you can do the same with this just two lines of code, `NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"FolderName LIKE [cd] %@",searchText];
    [SearchData filterUsingPredicate:predicate];`